# Refresh button without prompt on symfony

Tags: symfony, page-refresh

I need make a button for refresh a page withe the same values POST in bafore form.

The flow work is: Form1(values) > show | show > refresh button (with the same values ion From1)

I try with javascript but allways get Prompt (resend data?). So, I make a other form(Form2) for the refresh with all fields hidden and i want put all values on Form1 in the Form2 fields.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution... but is not simple.

Frist, we need the 2 forms, the form for introduce the data, and the form with the same fields but hidden.

So, we need pass the data from the first form in return of the action in controller, and then, in the view reassign this data to hidden fields from from 2.

I use Twig for this.

I hope that it's usefull for other persons whit the same problem.